# How to interpret results of a Clustering Heart Failure Dataset

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am doing an analysis about this dataset: [click](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Heart+failure+clinical+records)

In this dataset there are 13 features, 12 of input and 1 is the target variable, called "DEATH_EVENT". I tried to predict the survival of the patients in this dataset, using the features.
Hoewever, now I was trying to do a cluster analysis to see if the patients are grouped in clusters.
This is the code I have written.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
Features = ['ejection_fraction','serum_creatinine'] #the highest correlated features with death_event
X = heart_data[Features]

wcss = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i, init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=10, random_state=0)
    kmeans.fit(X)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
plt.plot(range(1, 11), wcss)
plt.title('Elbow Method')
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('WCSS')
plt.show()
```

[image: Elbow]
From this graph I can observe that there are 2 clusters. Now

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=10, random_state=0)
pred_y = kmeans.fit_predict(X)
plt.scatter(X["ejection_fraction"], X["serum_creatinine"])
plt.scatter(kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 0], kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 1], s=300, c='red')
plt.show()
```

And I obtained this chart:
[image: Centroids]

Now, what can I say from this chart? I think that it is unuseful, right?
I used only the features ejection_fraction and serum_creatinine because these are the only I used for the prediction. Or I have to use all the variables except from DEATH_EVENT? In this way:

```
X = heart_data.iloc[:, :11]
```

But in this case I obtain this:
[image: All features]

I am not able to understand these charts, I think that I am doing something wrong, but what? Where are the clusters? How to interpret these results?